# get binary operation code with clang python bindings

Tags: python, binding, clang, binary-operators

I use clang python bindings to parse my C++ code.When I get a cursor with BINARY_OPERATOR kind. I can't find a way to get the operator code.

I found there is a way to resolve it with modify clang's source code(https://reviews.llvm.org/D10833?id=39158#change-vBa6Es1Tcb5q). But that commit didn't merge to clang. And I just use clang with compiled binary so, is there any other way get the operation code without modify clang's source code?

Answer (score 1):

We can do something special to get the op by calculating the size of the left son.

Notice that if the cursor kind is BINARY_OPERATOR, the cursor will have two children node.

The length of the cursor.get_tokens() equals the sum of the token of left children, the right children and **the op**.

Therefore, we can get the op string as follows.

```py
def parse_binary_op(cursor: Cursor):
    assert cursor.kind == CursorKind.BINARY_OPERATOR
    children_list = [i for i in cursor.get_children()]
    assert len(children_list) == 2
    left_offset = len([i for i in children_list[0].get_tokens()])
    op = [i for i in cursor.get_tokens()][left_offset].spelling
    print(op)
```